# Fetchtype.LAZY with same Entity

Tags: java, jpa, recursion, spring-data

I build a tree structure which is stored in the database. The relation is build on the id, parent_id columns in the database table. I'm using spring data and hibernate.

For accessing the tree structure I build a entity class "Node" and a "NodeRepository". The entity class has an attribute "children" which has a @OneToMany relation to itself.

Fetching the nodes is no problem. But fetching the children is kind of a problem, because of lazy fetching outside of a transactional environment ("failed to lazily initialize a collection of role").

I changed the Fetchmode to eager. But that is also a problem because of the relation to itself, it ended up with the whole tree structure to be fetched.

So, what is the best practice in this case to keep the retrieval of the children easy on one side and don't fetching the whole structure on the other side?

Comment: I have no time to write up a full answer / look up a duplicate question, but I would advise you to read into *entity graphs*, a JPA 2.1 feature which is designed to dependably deal with conditional loading of lazy properties.

Comment: I already looked at @NamedEntityGraph but i think it will not solve my problem because of the recursive relation. At which point do I have to place the hint for get the children?

Comment: I never understood why Hibernate enforces the specification so lazy collections can't be loaded on detached entities. Personally this is one of the reasons I prefer  EclipseLink, because even though EclipseLink is the JPA reference implementation, they have chosen to break this rule, because it makes no sense, and is a complete pain for the developer.

Comment: Well, you can force Hibernate to initialize the collections without a transaction with "enable_lazy_load_no_trans". But i am still investigating on the disadvantages. I bet there are some.

Answer (score 1):

I think i got a solution which fits my needs.

First i defined a custom interface which extends my NodeRepository interface, give it an additional method "findOneWithChildrenInit" and implemented it.

```
public interface NodeRepositoryCustom {

    public Node findOneWithChildrenInit(Long id);

}

public class NodeRepositoryImpl implements NodeRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    NodeRepository repo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Node findOneWithChildrenInit(Long id) {
        Node node = repo.findOne(id);
        node.getChildren().size();
        return node;
    }

}
```

So I can decide. When I don't need the children, I can simply call findOne(). Then I need them, I call findOneWithChildrenInit().

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the provider implementation. But usually, the children collection is initialized when you use the collection, in any way. So, a common way is to call `children.size()` before you get out of the transaction, and throw away the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use lazy fetch type and make sure that session has not been closed by the time all children were fetched. You can simple do:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
// fetch all required Nodes & all their children by using the same session object
session.close();
```

Comment: what Session? OP refers to JPA (in tags)

Comment: I tried to receive a session from my EntityManagerFactory with "SessionFactory session_factory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);" and then open a new session from the session factory right before i access the children. I didn't work. I got the "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" exception.

Comment: You need to fetch Node entities using your new created session object first, and get list of children afterwards. Alternatively, if you're using spring in your project you can simply mark method where you fetch children list with @Transactional annotation, which will make sure that transaction will be remained open till the end of running thread.

Answer (score 0):

When you have one more relationship eager in your entity you need include the annotation `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` in the others eagers.

Check in [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/FetchMode.html) each of typer avaiables in the fetchmode.